# Create table with resulting strings

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jinja2

I`m trying to create a table which will contain result strings. My method should get a table of content from the database and return a JSON which then will be rendered as a table by jinja2 and showed to the user.

This table has 4 nesting levels. It represents how movers in a warehouse put goods on pallets.

This is the second table of two, and I already made first. I end up creating JSON with nested lists of dictionaries. Each container has 'info' where I store data about it.

But I want to find a better way to solve this problem.

JSON structure for first table:

```
Data
    info
        mission info
        number of nested lines
    containers
        container 0
            pallet 0
                number of boxes by type and sum of them
            pallet 1
                number of boxes by type and sum of them
        container №*
            info
                container type
                number of boxes by type and sum of them
                number of nested lines
            pallet 2
                number of boxes by type and sum of them
            pallet 3
                number of boxes by type and sum of them
    box_types
    total sum of boxes
```

Code for first Table:

```py
def sum_boxes(line, box_types, total):
    """boxes
        Returns sum of given type boxes"""
    for box in box_types:
        if box not in total:
            total.update({box: line[box]})
        else:
            total.update({box: line[box] + total[box]})

    return total


def get_provided_tare_and_boxes(data):
    """get_provided_tare_and_boxes
        Generating sql query depends on types of box_types used in current expedition.
        Execute it to get number of returnable packaging
        Create JSON that represents table structure which we need for  document"""

    # database query result
    res = [{'shop_num': 7, 'box_423': 0, 'box_417': 0, 'box_428': 0, 'box_0': 9, 'box_316': 0, 'box_416': 1,
            'po_emballage_2': 'AAB', 'box_616': 0, 'confirm_date': '16.07.2019', 'caliper': 19392670, 'box_617': 0,
            'container_number': 19398439, 'box_total': 11, 'box_622': 0, 'box_623': 1, 'mission_number': 39694,
            'box_411': 0},
           {'shop_num': 7, 'box_423': 0, 'box_417': 0, 'box_428': 0, 'box_0': 1, 'box_316': 0, 'box_416': 0,
            'po_emballage_2': 'AAB', 'box_616': 0, 'confirm_date': '16.07.2019', 'caliper': 19398181, 'box_617': 0,
            'container_number': 19398439, 'box_total': 1, 'box_622': 0, 'box_623': 0, 'mission_number': 39694,
            'box_411': 0}]


    data = dict()
    total_boxes_in_expedition = dict()
    containers = [i for i in set(i['container_number'] for i in res)]
    box_types = [i for i in res[0] if 'box_' in i]
    expedition_info = {i: res[0][i] for i in res[0] if i in ('shop_num', 'mission_number', 'confirm_date')}

    for container in containers:
        buffer = dict()
    buffer[str(container)] = dict()
    container_info = buffer[str(container)]['info'] = dict()
    supports = buffer[str(container)]['pallet'] = []
    total_boxes_in_container = dict()

    for lines in res:
        if
    lines['container_number'] == container:
    total_boxes_in_caliper = dict()
    total_boxes_in_caliper = sum_boxes(lines, box_types, total_boxes_in_caliper)
    supports.append({**{'caliper': lines['caliper'], 'pallet_type': lines['pallet_type']},
                     **total_boxes_in_caliper})
    total_boxes_in_container = sum_boxes(lines, box_types, total_boxes_in_container)
    total_boxes_in_expedition = sum_boxes(lines, box_types, total_boxes_in_expedition)

    if container != 0:
        container_info.update({**{'pallet_type': buffer[str(container)]['pallet'][0]['pallet_type']},
                               **total_boxes_in_container})

    container_info.update({'length': len(supports) + 1, 'container_number': int(container)})
    data.update({container: buffer[str(container)]})

    length = len(data) + 1
    for i in data:
        length += len(data[i]['pallet'])
    expedition_info.update({'length': length})


    return json.dumps({'msg': 'Done', 'data': data, 'box_types': sorted([box.strip('box_') for box in box_types]),
                           'info': expedition_info, 'total': total_boxes_in_expedition})
```

Glossary:

P - Pallets that contain goods of same type(if C==0 then this if full pallet of same goods)

C - Pallet that contain 2+ type of goods.

G - Goods on pallets

B* - Number of boxes(B1, B2, B3 - represent type of box)

[Table overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCEpn.png)

Comment: A parallel suggestion: why not using Flask and its models?

Comment: For now project structures such way that we generates JSON out of sql request and it then render to web pages. My problem not in choosing better tool for the job, but in creating right data structure.

Comment: Which is one of Flask's core features, this is why I suggested investigating. But I also understand that this is out of the question scope, good luck with it!